# Matrix Terminology German/English

Tags: matrices

I'm a bit confused with the German/English translation of the following terminology. Could you please help me fill in the two questionmarks **Q1** and **Q2**? Is the rest correct?

| Matrix | German | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ | Matrix | Matrix |
| $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ | (Zeilen)Stufenform | **Q1?** |
| $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ | **Q2?** | Row Echelon Form (ref) |
| $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ | Reduzierte (Zeilen)Stufenform Normierte (Zeilen)Stufenform | Reduced Row Echelon Form (rref) |

Comment: Q1 = Q2, cf. https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Row%20Echelon%20Form

Comment: Stufenform = (matrix in reduced) echelon form, and *Zeilen Stufenform* = (matrix) reduced by rows, or lines. Normierte is like normalized, what some of us call canonical reduced form (every line's leading element is one and all the rest of the elements in that element's COLUMN is zero)

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing this is exactly what is confusing me. In german texts I always see the form with any leading number refered to as Zeilenstufenform whereas in english texts is always see the form with leading one's only refered to as row echelon form.